# Looping through files error

Tags: python

I have a loop supposed to iterate through a list of files

```
import os
for fil in os.listdir('dir/'):
    with open(fil) as f:
        for line in f:
            #process line
```

My files contain text but they have weird extensions such as `filea.234234 fileb.34234`

When I run the script I get the error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filea.234234'
```

What is the cause of this error?

ps. The are way too many files to rename them if that is the cause

Comment: Try looking at the contents of the list returned by `os.listdir('dir/')`

Comment: And no, this has nothing to do with the filename extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those files are located under `dir/`, not in the working directory. You are trying to open `./filea.234234`, while you should be opening `dir/filea.234234`. Fix your code accordingly:

```
import os

for fil in os.listdir('dir/'):
    with open(os.path.join("dir", fil)) as f:
        for line in f:
            # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#module-glob) module:

```
import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('dir', '*')):
    # etc...
```

In either case you might want to make sure the filename is not a directory before trying to open it, depending on whether or not you can be sure the directory only contains files.